# Is there a better vba code that deletes all empty lines (not spaces) in a textbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with a textbox and a command button in Excel. When there is a text in the textbox and I hit the command button, it deletes empty lines, but not all of them. It keeps a few empty lines there. How can I adjust the code below so it will delete all empty lines? (not spaces)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim A$, I&
    A = TextBox1
    Do
        I = Len(A)
        A = Replace(A, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)
    Loop While Len(A) <> I
    TextBox1 = A
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems VB script. Maybe you can use C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine to me. The only problem I can see is when you have a line-break that is *not* `vbCrLf` (e.g., just `vbCr` or just `vbLf`).

In any case, instead of having a loop that runs and keeps replacing line-breaks, you may use Regular Expressions for this.

Try something like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    regEx.Global = True
    regEx.Pattern = "[\r\n]{2,}"
    TextBox1.Text = regEx.Replace(TextBox1.Text, vbNewLine)
End Sub
```

**Note:**

You'll need to add the `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions x.x` reference. Alternatively, you may use late binding:

```
Dim regEx As Object
Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
```

Comment: Awesome! It works like a charm. Thanks a lot, you're a star.